# Why is my std::queue in my Queue class not empty?

Tags: c++, c++14

Why is my `std::queue` in my Queue class not empty?

Each time I initialise the queue it is empty in the constructor but returns a non-zero size when I call the class method size().

Here is a MWE:

```
/ TEST QUEUE
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>

#include <Eigen/Dense>

template <class dtype> 
class Queue {
    private:
    std::queue<dtype> q;
    std::mutex qmtx;
    std::condition_variable qcond;

    bool start = false; 
    bool display = false;
    public:
    Queue(bool sstart, bool qdisplay) : start(sstart), display(qdisplay) 
    {
        std::clog << "In q constructor: " << q.size() << std::endl;
    }

    // Method to push values on to queue
    void push(const dtype & message); 
    dtype pop(); 
    void stop();
    bool empty();
    bool size();
    bool clear();
};
```

And my .cpp

```
template<typename dtype>
dtype Queue<dtype>::pop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(qmtx);
    qcond.wait(lock, [&]() { return !q.empty() | start; } );

    if (!start) {
        std::clog << "The queue has stopped popping." << std::endl;
    }

    dtype ret = q.front();
    q.pop();

    return ret;
}

// Method to push values on to queue
template<typename dtype>
void Queue<dtype>::push(const dtype & message) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(qmtx);
    if (display) { std::clog << "Qpush Locked." << std::endl; }
    q.push(message);
    qcond.notify_one();
}

template<typename dtype>
void Queue<dtype>::stop() {
    start = false;
    qcond.notify_all();
}

template<typename dtype>
bool Queue<dtype>::empty() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(qmtx);
    q.empty();
}

template<typename dtype>
bool Queue<dtype>::size() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(qmtx);
    q.size();
}

template<typename dtype>
bool Queue<dtype>::clear() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(qmtx);
    std::queue<dtype> empty;
    std::swap(q, empty);
}

int main () {
    Queue<Eigen::VectorXd> YQ(false, false);
    std::cout << YQ.size() << std::endl;
}
```

I am not sure what else to write?

Comment: `size` shouldn't return a `bool`.

Comment: Ok. But why didn't I get a compile error?

Comment: @fatm Your code has undefined behavior, since you have functions that suppose to return a `bool` but do not return anything.  Thus your code cannot be reasoned with until you fix those errors and rerun your program.  Whether `size` should return a `bool` is another separate issue -- right now, the program is basically useless until you actually return something from those functions.

Comment: Ah. Even worse.